# Drawing string on uiview over contentview of tableviewcell draws same content again and again

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

Because using three labels over `UITableViewCell` slowed down tableview scroll performance I tried drawing directly on `UIView` that I dragged over the prototype cell. While this significantly improved scroll performance, this got me into another problem.

Actually I am drawing the contents of a feed. After six or seven unique rows (for 20 records), rows are duplicate. They show the same content starting from top of tableview. However When I tap on those repeated cells the content changes to what it should have been.

After researching I found six or seven is the number of rows actually visible on the screen. So this should have been display update error but I am not sure should I do to fix this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"newsCell";
    NewsCell *cell = (NewsCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (indexPath.row < feeds.count) {
        dict =  [feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell setNewsHeading:[dict objectForKey:@"title"] pubDate:[dict objectForKey:@"pubDate"] newsExcerpt:[dict objectForKey:@"attributedDescription"]];
    }
    dict = nil;
    return cell;
} 

-(void)setNewsHeading:(NSString *)newsHeading pubDate:(NSString *)pubDate newsExcerpt:(NSAttributedString *)newsExcerpt 
{
    self.newsView.newsHeading = newsHeading;
    self.newsView.pubDate = pubDate;
    self.newsView.newsExcerpt = newsExcerpt;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [feeds count];
}
```

Comment: Can show your code for `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`?

Comment: Are you downloading the feeds while updating the tableView or the feeds are already fully downloaded before being displayed in tableView?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like it could be a caching issue - have you tried overriding the `prepareForReuse` method in your cell subclass to reset the cell contents back to the default values?

Comment: No I haven't. How do I use that?

Comment: Its seems like its working by using [self.newsview setNeedsDisplay]. However scrolling performance degraded which was the whole point of manually drawing on UIView. Is there anything else I can do to clear UIView?